# Create an elsif statement in Rails API?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, api, controller

I am trying to receive a JSON post to my Rails 3 application. The JSON post is just an email with a subject which will be one of the following:

```
BACKUP_PASS/VERIFY_PASS
BACKUP_FAIL/VERIFY_FAIL
BACKUP_FAIL/VERIFY_PASS
etc..
```

I have the following code in my controller:

```
def backupnotification
  email_payload = JSON.parse(params[:payload])
  Activity.create(:action => 'failed to backup', :details => email_payload['recipient'], :user_id => '28')
end
```

I've also added the following to my routes file:

```
post  '/api/activity/backupnotification' => 'activities#backupnotification'
```

Obviously, this would create a new `Activity` record regardless of the backup status. What I would like to do is create an activity with an action of `failed to backup` if the term FAIL appears anywhere in the subject, and `successfully backed up` if the term FAIL does not exist.

The JSON post (email_payload) includes an attribute called `subject`. I was wondering if I could do something like this:

```
if email_payload['subject'] => "FAIL"
 ...
else
 ...
end
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: This is not the rails way. Controller actions should not check whether a request is GET or POST, that is where routes are for.

Comment: I have used routes for the post check `post  '/api/activity/backupnotification' => 'activities#backupnotification'`

Comment: Yes, but it seems that your GET request goes to the same action.

Comment: Ah sorry, that was added to check the routing was working. I'll remove it now.

Comment: That makes the question a lot clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can access your subject in a similar way as your recipient, you can try something like this.

```
def backupnotification

  email_payload = JSON.parse(params[:payload])

  if email_payload['subject'].include?('FAIL')
    action_message = 'failed to backup'
  else
    action_message = 'successfully backed up'
  end

  Activity.create(
    :action =>  action_message,
    :details => email_payload['recipient'],
    :user_id => '28')
end
```